# Pulling One Element From A CSV File

Tags: csv, for-loop

I'm trying to write a function that will return the most recent 'closing' value in a csv file containing the data of a cryptocurrency. The csv file contains 6 columns and about 900 rows and I'm looking to only pull one element of the table.

However, I seem to faced a fair bit of difficulty in pulling this off for some reason. The function below returns values from the column I want, however it seems to be pulling values from the very bottom of the document (whereas I want the most recent values).

Also, just a side note to explain what I was attempting to do with the 'count'. Since I'm expecting the value I want to be located on the second row, I wanted my for loop to only iterate through two lines of the file. However, as the result of the function went on to reveal to me, as it currently stands with the counter I'm returning two values from the function.

I understand there must be a much less convoluted way of getting the information I need so am open to any solution to the problem. Though, that being said, I'd be really interested to see where I went wrong here as I'm fairly new to Python.

Thanks a lot!

```
def csv_to_close(csv_file):
    with open(f"{csv_file}.csv", 'r') as csvfile:
        csv_file = csv.reader(csvfile)

        running = True
        count = 0
        while running == True:
            if count < 2:
                for column in csv_file:
                    close = column[4]
                    count += 1
            else:
                running = False
                print(close)
```